# AWS IOT Reconnecting Issue

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm trying to connect mqtt with using AWSMqttManager on Android. I follow this sample code for this. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSubWebSocket.

I tried app on Android version 7.1.1 and 4.4.4.

Android 7.1.1 successfully connected. But I can't connect to Android 4.4.4.

```
mqttManager.connect(credentialsProvider, AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback { status, throwable ->
                runOnUiThread {
                    if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connecting) {
                        logThis("Connecting...")

                    } else if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Connected) {
                        logThis("Connected")

                    } else if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.Reconnecting) {
                        if (throwable != null) {
                            logThis("Connection error.")
                        }
                        logThis("Reconnecting")
                    } else if (status == AWSIotMqttClientStatus.ConnectionLost) {
                        if (throwable != null) {
                            logThis("Connection error.")
                            throwable.printStackTrace()
                        }
                        logThis("Disconnected")
                    } else {
                        logThis("Disconnected")

                    }
                }
            })
```

It keeps on reconnected without even being connected once on Android 4.4.4.
Aws Iot sdk version is 2.6.12 :

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:2.6.12'
```

Logcat:

```
Connecting...
Reconnecting
Reconnecting
Reconnecting
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: What I know is this has been an issue with Android 4.4.3 and 4.4.4 and AWS support teams have described this earlier as well. These versions had a problem with BANDWIDTH and thus have to be tackled separately.

Comment: So what can I do for this ?

Comment: I checked the entire thing and looks fine. The issue is with the file installs for Android 4.4.4. Reset the settings and do it again and independently. It will work.

Comment: No It doesn't work. I'm facing issue Android 5.0.2

Comment: It works just fine on my 5.1.1 android device.